# Show Intranet page on the Internet from another published application

Tags: java, servlets, intranet

We have the following situation:  There is an application that works on Apache and IIS.  Internally, we use it with IIS (port 80) and on the internet we use Apache (port 8443).

We developed an interface (ASP.NET) to integrate the application with a vendor (all working fine).  The interface is accessible only internally (port 88 on same server).  These causes the interface to work only when users are in our internal network, but not when they try to use it from the internet, because the browser cannot reach the ASP.NET page.

Is there a way to, have the published application call the ASP.NET page internally and somehow display it to the user without the need to publishing the ASP.NET page to the internet?

We saw that the published application is able to do this, as it also calls it's reporting application, which resides in another server and is not published, but somehow, using a Java Servlet, it calls the reports and displays them, even from the internet.

As an example:

AP1:
Intranet: htp://server.domain/ap1/
Internet: htps://site.com/

Interface:
Intranet: htp://server.domain/int/
Internet: No

Reports:
Intranet: htp://server1.domain/rep/
Internet: No

AP1 calling Reports:
Intranet: htp://server.domain/ap1/report_url
Internet: htps://site.com/report_url

We have been doing research to check if it is possible to "bridge" the ASP.NET interface and call it from the application even when the application is called from the internet (like have the call to the interface made by the server internally and not by the client).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting up Apache as a proxy for the internal application with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)?

Comment: I have no idea of how that works, but I will do some research and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I have no idea of how that works, but I will do some research and let you know how it goes.  Thanks for the reply.